# How can I create a custom decomposition tree chart in python

Tags: python, pandas, visualization

I want to create a decomposition tree chart in python but one that's slightly different than the one available in Power BI. The structure I want to create is very similar to the Power BI version, with one difference being that I want to have a layer of sub-nodes/child-nodes which would be just titles without any number associated to them (named 'sub-child' in the attached image).

Another difference would be that in Power BI, the shape of each node is a thin horizontal bar, whereas in my attached image, its a square/rectangular box with the text inside of it rather than outside (as compared to Power BI). But the first difference I mentioned is a more important requirement for the chart I want to make.

Sample image of decomposition tree chart as required:

[sample image of decomposition tree chart as required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtBWM.png)

I have gone through many available charts in pandas/plotly/etc for my purpose but I couldn't find any that fit my need.

Note: I have the data available in a pandas dataframe, but I don't mind changing it to any other format that would be required to make the chart.

Here's the code for creating the sample data.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Parent': ['Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent',
                              'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent', 'Parent'],
                   'Child': ['Child 1', 'Child 1', 'Child 1', 'Child 1', 'Child2', 'Child2',
                             'Child2', 'Child2', 'Child3', 'Child3', 'Child3', 'Child3'],
                   'Child-Values': ['40%', '40%', '40%', '40%', '35%', '35%', '35%', '35%', '25%',
                                    '25%', '25%', '25%'],
                   'Sub-Child': ['Sub-child 1', 'Sub-child 1', 'Sub-child 2', 'Sub-child 2',
                                'Sub-child 1', 'Sub-child 1', 'Sub-child 2', 'Sub-child 2',
                                'Sub-child 1', 'Sub-child 1', 'Sub-child 2', 'Sub-child 2'],
                   'Sub-Sub-Child': ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'A1', 'A2',
                                    'B1', 'B2'],
                   'Sub-Sub-Child-Values': ['40%', '60%', '25%', '75%', '80%', '20%', '45%',
                                            '55%', '35%', '65%', '30%', '70%']})
```

I have tried using the treeplotter library made by 'Luke-Poeppel'. Here's a link to their github repo (its also the code I have used):

https://github.com/Luke-Poeppel/treeplotter/blob/master/Tutorial.md

I'm not sure why but I get an error in the last line of the code (the create_tree_diagram function) that says that its parameters are missing - even though I have used the exact same code given in the repo.

Does anyone know how I can make this type of a chart in python? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi! I made this tool. I haven’t looked at it in a while, but I’ll investigate the error very soon (and respond here).